Is there Connect By Prior, connect_by_root & sys_connect_by_path function available in pyspark?
I am working on converting big oracle query into pyspark.
In oracle query  Connect_by_root, sys_connect_by_path and connect by prior
are used .
Is there any way we can achieve it in pyspark ? or any logic can be build at sql level.
